# How to restrict pages to a user in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce

I am working on a site and there I am using `woocommerce`.

If the user logged in or not, they can add to cart a product, go to cart, go to checkout. But now I want that only logged in users can access these pages.

If the guest user click on the add to cart button the message appear `You must be logged in`. If user go to cart page or checkout page they redirect to register page.

Is there any plugin or hook in Woocommerce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131562/make-woocommerce-pages-accessible-for-logged-in-users-only

Put this in your **functions.php** file:

```
function wpse_131562_redirect() {
    if (
        ! is_user_logged_in()
        && (is_woocommerce() || is_cart() || is_checkout())
    ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_131562_redirect');
```

What does it do?
We check if a not-logged-in user wants to see a WooCommerce page, and redirect him/her to our home page.

In your case, you can customize the redirect to the *You must be logged* page.