# Restrict Contact page allowing only logged in users in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, restriction

I am building a ecommerce website with WooCommerce (8.1.1) and Divi theme.
I found how to restrict access to WooCommerce pages to log in users, but I want to restrict Contact Page, which I created, to WooCommerce log in users.
I suppose I have to customize functions.php found here ([How to restrict pages to a user in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942890/how-to-restrict-pages-to-a-user-in-woocommerce)) ?
Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, that will redirect unlogged users to My Account page, when trying to access the contact page:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'contact_page_unlogged_users_redirect');
function contact_page_unlogged_users_redirect() {
    $targeted_page = 'contact'; // <== Set the desired page slug

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( $targeted_page ) ) {
        // feel free to customize the following line to suit your needs
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.

Comment: thank you @LoicTheAztec for your help ! I don't want to redirect to home page, so I tried to changed the last code line. wp_redirect(home_url('/mon-compte'));